# Rails 4 - Failed to allocate memory error when parsing large spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing an app that involves getting an Excel spreadsheet that has about 400k rows from a remote server and parsing the data into the rails app. I am using Roo and I've searched around but I haven't found any other questions that deal with Roo, Rails and this particular error. My code is:

```
def self.import
f = open("http://www.bced.gov.bc.ca/reporting/odefiles/likert_responses_consolidated_2011to2014.xlsx")

xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(f, extension: :xlsx)

xlsx.each(name: "SCHOOL_NAME", question: 'SURVEY_QUESTION', many_or_all_responses: 'MANY_OR_ALL_RESPONSES',
          at_no_time_responses: 'AT_NO_TIME_RESPONSES', few_times_responses: 'FEW_TIMES_RESPONSES',
          some_times_responses: 'SOME_TIMES_RESPONSES') do |hash|
  school_name = hash[:name].split(' ')[0...-1].join(' ')
  if School.exists?(name: school_name)
    school = School.find_by_name(school_name)
    if !Survey.exists?(question: hash[:question]) && has_data?(hash)
      school.surveys.create(question: hash[:question], many_or_all_responses: hash[:many_or_all_responses], at_no_time_responses: hash[:at_no_time_responses],
                    few_times_responses: hash[:few_times_responses], some_times_responses: hash[:some_times_responses])
    elsif has_data?(hash)
      survey = Survey.find_by_question(hash[:question])
      survey.many_or_all_responses += hash[:many_or_all_responses]
      survey.at_no_time_responses += hash[:at_no_time_responses]
      survey.few_times_responses += hash[:few_times_responses]
      survey.some_times_responses += hash[:some_times_responses]
    end
  end
end
end
```

However, this doesn't work when pulling the file from the remote server as shown and I get:

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

whenever I try and call the function. I then tried copying only a few rows into a new file and parsing that and the function works fine. However, I want it to be able to grab it from the remote without having me first modify it manually. Is there any way I can do so?